# How to Connect WeatherlLnk on Raspberry pi 4 using Windows 10 arm?

Tags: windows-10, usb, raspberry-pi

Recenlty I decided to buy a Raspberry pi 4 model in order to use it as a tiny weather server with
a Davis Weather Station. Unfortunally i was not so familiar with arm architecture and i wanded to
avoid console enviroment so i sucessfully installed Windows 10 arm.

As i was not sure about the ability of running in a correct way in rashberry
the related software that comes with weather station (weather link) i tried succesfully
to install some simple programms using *compatibility to XP mode* in orer to by pass the
fact that i was running software on arm architecture.

Then i tried to install the Weatherlink Software with no problems but finally i can not
communicate with weather station via USB. The weather station seems that has no drivers
althought i have installed the program of the Weather Sation. Moreover if i try to use USB mode
in reinstall instalation freezes completely.

Could someone help me or suggest me a solution?

I am aware that i might tring to use incompatible software for ARM architecture but i would
appreciate if i could have a solution here using Windows 10.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not clear, but are you trying to install x86 software onto the Arm? If so, then it will just not work.

Comment: @Bib - x86 software will work on Windows 10 on ARM, but I would be dubious of a x86 driver, working on Windows on ARM even if it’s a USB device.

Comment: "Compatibility mode" does not mean emulation of a different architecture, all it means is that the operating system appears as if it were the previous version allowing a Windows XP program (of the same architecture) to *maybe* function. If you need an x86 architecture then chances are you need some kind of Intel NUC or Compute Stick or small form factor PC. A Raspberry Pi may be cheap but it is no replacement for the x86 platform when you have devices that only work on or only have drivers for x86.

Comment: You may want to look at http://www.joejaworski.com/weather/ or https://www.google.com/search?q=Davis+Weather+Station+linux